# mplfinance plot not saving when called outside of plot command

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I'm new to matplotlib. I'm struggling to customise elements of my plot within the first *.plot* call. For example, *ylabel* works but *xlabel* doesn't. I was hoping I could separate the *savefig* command so that I could add/modify elements of the plot between the first *.plot* call and the *savefig* call (because all the examples I see online seem to create the plot and then modify elements separately, i.e. the line *fplt.xlabel("Blah")*

I notice that a lot of plot examples I found online (for line graphs and such) provide all x and y values separately, but I like the plot technique I've used as it automatically uses high, low, etc. to create candles.

So why does this code work:

```
            fplt.plot(
                    dft,
                    type="candle",
                    style='charles',
                    addplot=extraPlot2,
                    ylabel=stock,
#                    xlabel="Blah", <= removed as doesn't work
                    figratio=(10, 6), volume=True,
                    savefig=dict(
                        fname=folder2,
                        bbox_inches="tight"
                    )
            )
```

But this code doesn't (even with the hashes added):

```
            fplt.plot(
                    dft,
                    type="candle",
                    style='charles',
                    addplot=extraPlot2,
                    ylabel=stock,
#                    xlabel="Blah", <= removed as doesn't work
                    figratio=(10, 6), volume=True,
            )
#            fplt.xlabel("Blah") <= would like to do this if I can get savefig to work
#           fplt.xticks(rotation=45) <= i'd also like to do stuff like this
            fplt.savefig(folder2)
```

I've tried making *fplt.plot* a variable and targeting that but with no luck.
Apologies for any poor terminology, I am very new to this.

EDIT: Imports added below for reference. And I realise why *xlabel* wasn't working now, as I see I was importing it.

```
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib.pyplot import bar, xlabel
from numpy import False_, NaN
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
from tkinter import EXCEPTION, Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import mplfinance as fplt
from pathlib import Path
```

Comment: If you look at the source code for mplfinance you can see the list of valid keyword arguments for the `plot` function here https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/plotting.py#L100. It doesn't look like `'xlabel'` is included in there, although `ylabel` is. You may want to submit a github issue asking if/why this option is not available https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate is written by the mplfinance package creator.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the Matplotlib pyplot module and use the [`gcf()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gcf) ("get current figure") function to return a [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure) object. It is the `Figure` object that has the [`savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) method. E.g.,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot

# your code here

fig = plt.gcf()  # gcf is "get current figure"
fig.savefig(folder2)
```

Looking at [this mplfinance issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/427) it also looks like you can return the figure object with:

```
fig, axlist = fplt.plot(..., returnfig=True)

# save figure
fig.savefig(folder2)
```

Comment: Imports now added. I think *mplfinance* deals with the candlestick element. Perhaps I should be using ```import mplfinance as mplf; from matplotlib import pyplot as fplt```

Comment: You can do `import mplfiance as fplt`, but you'll also need to do, say, `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`, and instead to `fig = plt.gcf()`

Comment: I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Now using ```import mplfinance as fplt from matplotlib; import pyplot as plt``` the plotting works. However when I try to further customise the chart i.e. ```plt.xticks(rotation = 90)```, this just gets ignored. I've tried placing it at various locations with no luck (and no errors thrown).

Comment: P.S I know I can use mltfinance *xrotation=90*, but I was hoping to have access to matplotlib customisations, as there seem to be more.

Comment: For most control you're best off accessing methods of the [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class) class. The axes are returned by the second option I gave in my answer (also see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects)) or using `axlist = plt.gca()`. If you use the Axes you can use, e.g., `xlabels = axlist[-1].get_xticklabels(); axlist[-2].set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45)`

Comment: This worked, thanks. Can now access sizes, amongst other things, i.e. ```axlist[2].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=7); axlist[0].set_ylabel(stock, fontsize=16)```